# Alternative axiomatic derivation of the Shannon entropy

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I'm actually interested in the derivation of the information measure $I(p)=-\log p$ of a single event of probability $p$, as the Shannon entropy can then be defined as the average over all events. Strangely enough, I could only find two axiomatic derivations of $I$ itself, of which the one mentioned [here](https://csustan.csustan.edu/%7Etom/Lecture-Notes/Information-Theory/info-lec.pdf#page=16) is the less restrictive:

1. $I(p)\ge 0$ and $I(1)=0$;
2. $I(p_1 p_2)=I(p_1)+I(p_2)$;
3. $I$ is continuous.

My question is whether condition (3) could be replaced with the condition that $I$ be monotonically decreasing. More generally, I'm looking for a simple derivation that makes use of both condition (1) and the monotonicity argument (less probable events should be more informative).

**Edit**ed out proof attempt as per comments.

Comment: Hint: show $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ with $f(x):=I(e^x)$. That $f$ is monotonic [famously implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) it's linear.

Comment: The $\log$ solution comes by reducing the problem to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), and there are weaker conditions than continuity that prove linearity of solutions to the same. Monotonicity is indeed one of these.

Comment: I just noticed that probably condition (2) can even be replaced with the weaker condition that $I(np)=nI(p)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, but then Cauchy's argument cannot be used.

Comment: Just as another comment on this, I was able to find an even simpler derivation of $I$ in Hankerson, [*Introduction to Information Theory and Data Compression*](https://iasbs.ac.ir/~s.taghavi/courses/2019/winter/informationTheory/[Information%20Theory%20Data%20Compression][2nd][2003][Hankerson,Harris,Johnson].pdf#page=41) that doesn't even use monotonicity.